# Microphone not detected after HDMI output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, microphone, tv

This seems similar as [Headphone & microphone plug not detected if sound output device is HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308255/headphone-microphone-plug-not-detected-if-sound-output-device-is-hdmi)

I want to share my Ubuntu 21.04 screen with a TV screen (thus having 2 screens). I also want to specify sound ouputs for various programs. For example, I want Chrome to output its sound to my computer headphones, and I want Firefox to output its sound to the TV screen (which has speakers).
For this, I use pavucontrol and it works wonderfully.

But after that, chrome does not detect my microphone anymore (Web Discord or Google Meets do not detect my microphone, but it usually works otherwise). Note that in the Sound parameters of Ubuntu, my microphone is detected.

How to fix this ?